# Send multiple logs from filebeat to logstash in a timely manner

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have a server where all logs are present in a directory.

Now these files are separated by date. How can I setup filebeat such that all log files from these are sent to kibana (and how to configure this) on other server to receive logs in the same timely manner in a single file.

For example: in server A: I have 40 log files for last 40 days of log

I want these 40 logs in a timely manner, from oldest to newest in a single file in other server.

And also the file with today's date will be updating with new logs.

I have configured filebeat and logstash such that sync is being maintained, but the logs are not in timely manner because of which I'm facing problem in processing it by some of my logic.

glob pattern

```
/directory to logs/*.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to remotely sync a set of log files to a single file in time sorted order using filebeat and logstash then...

If you set the harvester_limit to 1, so that only one file is processed at a time, then I think you can use scan.order and scan.sort to get filebeat to send the data in the right order. logstash is more of a problem. In the current version you can disable the java execution engine ('pipeline.java_execution: false' in logstash.yml) and set '--pipeline.workers 1', in which case logstash will preserve order.

In future releases I do not forsee elastic maintaining two execution engines, so once the ruby execution engine is retired it will not be possible to prevent events being re-ordered in the pipeline (the java engine routinely re-orders events in the pipeline in reproducible but unpredicatable ways).